# Ag-grid cellDoubleClicked event is firing twice on FAST double clicking the cell but works fine with little slow double clicking

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am using Ag-grid in Angular 8 project. I have got stuck at one function call where i am using ag-grid's double click event. When cellDoubleClicked event gets fire, i am calling one method. But its calling that method twice if I quickly double click the grid's cell. But it works fine in slow down my mouse double clicking speed.
What i did so far is in TS file declared the method and put console log. also i have put event in html and assigned callback function.

**In my.Component.html file**

```
<ag-grid-angular>
  [columnDef] = "columnDef"
  [rowData] = "rowData"
  (gridReady) = "onGridReady($event)"
  (cellClicked) = "onCellClicked($event)"
  (cellDoubleClicked) = "onCellDoubleClicked($event)"
</ag-grid-angular>
```

**In my.Component.ts file**

```
IMPORTS GOES HERE...

export class MyComponent implements OnInit {


  OTHER LOGIC GOES HERE...


 onCellDoubleClicked($event){

     console.log("method called"); //This will be called 2 times if you fast/quickly double click the cell. It should call once only

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [SOLVED]

This was the Ag-Grid framework issue itself. The issue has been fixed in Ag-Grid version 22.1.0. You might face this mouse double click issue if your Ag-Grid version is lower than 22.1.0. So, Make sure if you are planning to upgrade to version 23.xx then follow this [migration guide](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-themes-v23-migration/) from ag-grid.
Please visit the link below and search for **onCellDoubleClicked** to see ag-grid's changelog **link:** https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-changelog/